# Group by column to get array results in Postgresql

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have a table called `moviegenre` which looks like:

```
moviegenre:
- movie (FK movie.id)
- genre (FK genre.id)
```

I have a query (ORM generated) which returns all `movie.imdb` and `genre.id`'s which have `genre.id`'s in common with a given `movie.imdb_id`.

```
SELECT "movie"."imdb_id", 
       "moviegenre"."genre_id" 
FROM   "moviegenre" 
       INNER JOIN "movie" 
               ON ( "moviegenre"."movie_id" = "movie"."id" ) 
WHERE  ( "movie"."imdb_id" IN (SELECT U0."imdb_id" 
                               FROM   "movie" U0 
                                      INNER JOIN "moviegenre" U1 
                                              ON ( U0."id" = U1."movie_id" ) 
                               WHERE  ( U0."last_ingested_on" IS NOT NULL 
                                        AND NOT ( U0."imdb_id" IN 
                                                  ( 'tt0169547' ) ) 
                                        AND NOT ( U0."imdb_id" IN 
                                                  ( 'tt0169547' ) ) 
                                        AND U1."genre_id" IN ( 2, 10 ) )) 
         AND "moviegenre"."genre_id" IN ( 2, 10 ) )
```

The problem is that I'll get results in the format:

```
[
  ('imdbid22`, 'genreid1'),
  ('imdbid22`, 'genreid2'),
  ('imdbid44`, 'genreid1'),
  ('imdbid55`, 'genreid8'),
]
```

Is there a way within the query itself I can group all of the genre ids into a list under the `movie.imdb_id`'s? I'd like do to grouping in the query.
Currently doing it in my web app code (Python) which is extremely slow when 50k+ rows are returned.

```
[
  ('imdbid22`, ['genreid1', 'genreid2']),
  ('imdbid44`, 'genreid1'),
  ('imdbid55`, 'genreid8'),
]
```

thanks in advance!

edit:

here's the python code which runs against the current results

results_list = []

```
for item in movies_and_genres:
    genres_in_common = len(set([
        i['genre__id'] for i in movies_and_genres
        if i['movie__imdb_id'] == item['movie__imdb_id']
    ]))
    imdb_id = item['movie__imdb_id']

    if genres_in_common >= min_in_comon:
        result_item = {
            'movie.imdb_id': imdb_id,
            'count': genres_in_common
        }
        if result_item not in results_list:
            results_list.append(result_item)

return results_list
```

Comment: If your code is slow on 50k rows it means you're doing it wrong. And without  knowing your ORM giving a solution won'y be easy

Comment: The code is a fast as it can be, its just that it must loop over 50k rows then 50k rows within each iteration in order to do that grouping.

Comment: What is slow your current output? Are you achieving expected output with python code now?

Comment: The python is the bottleneck, it takes 80,000ms

Comment: @FJones99 Yes that's the wrong approach. Build a new associative array and then append to it like arr['movieid'][] = genreid (however you do that in Python). It's a single loop.

Comment: I've added the python code to the first post

Comment: Why is this tagged `sql` and `postgresql` when the code is actually Python? Why isn't it tagged `python` ?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu because the code is not relevant since the solution is possible in SQL

Comment: @FJones99 And, are you expecting a solution in SQL or a solution with an ORM-approach? Also, you can't generate in SQL items in this form `(imdbid22', ['genre1', 'genre2'])` - You can write a query to return items that are part of the same `imdbid22` in a concatenated string, separated by commans, but you would then have to parse and split each string (so, I don't feel like you'd be able to get a huge or even an improvement at all from this kind of approach).

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Actually postgres supports arrays, the question is if the ORM supports that.

Comment: @JakubKania But can you return a result set that has in the 1st column a string, `imdbid22` and in the 2nd column an array?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Yeah, sure, why not? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html

Comment: @JakubKania Cool, didn't know postgres could do that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select m.imdb_id, array_agg(g.genre_id) as genre_id
from
    moviegenre g
    inner join 
    movie m on g.movie_id = m.id
where 
    m.last_ingested_on is not null 
    and not m.imdb_id in ('tt0169547')  
    and not m.imdb_id in ('tt0169547')
    and g.genre_id in (2, 10) 
group by m.imdb_id
```

`array_agg` will create an array of all the `genre_ids` of a certain `imdb_id`:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE

Comment: Does `array_agg[g.genre_id]` aggregates all result? . If you could explain the fun and argument that would be great

Comment: what is "moviegenre g" the single letter variable names make this unreadable

Comment: @FJones99 `g` is an alias for genre. Single letter aliases are quite common in SQL, as they make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I hope python code will be fast enough:

```
movielist = [
  ('imdbid22', 'genreid1'),
  ('imdbid22', 'genreid2'),
  ('imdbid44, 'genreid1'),
  ('imdbid55', 'genreid8'),
]
dict = {}
for items in movielist:
    if dict[items[0]] not in dict:
        dict[items[0]] = items[1]
    else:
        dict[items[0]] = dict[items[0]].append(items[1])        
print dict
```

Output:

```
{'imdbid44': ['genreid1'], 'imdbid55': ['genreid8'], 'imdbid22': ['genreid1', 'genreid2']}
```

If you just need movie name, count:
Change this in original query you will get the answer you dont need python code

`SELECT "movie"."imdb_id", count("moviegenre"."genre_id")`

`group by "movie"."imdb_id"`

Comment: one issue is the function must return a list of dicts as the first post shows `[{'movie.imdb_id': 'someimdbid', 'count': 5}, {'movie.imdb_id': 'someimdbid2', 'count': 3}}`

Comment: you mean it has to be list instead of dictonary?

Comment: yes, list of dicts with keys 'movie.imdb_id', 'count'